# Unable to find the option in Selenium Firefox

Tags: selenium-ide

I've recently started learning Selenium, and in the tutorial there is an option as `verifyTextPresent`, in the tutorial, it is given as below.

```
Open the browser
start recording
select the text
right click on it
and there in options there is **verifyTextPresent** option
```

but when i was trying to do the same, i'm unable to find this option. So in my browser, i clicked on `Show All Available Commands` and it is giving me the below options, but unable to find the `verifyTextPresent` Option, please let me know how can i get `verifyTextPresent`.

But when i click in the `command` text box, there it is showing `verifyTextPresent`

[image]

Comment: Hi @MrunalGosar It is a plugin in Firefox to record.

Comment: Did you try to find this command on a specific input/button which contains text?

Comment: I tried it on direct text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> verifyTextPresent(pattern) This command is deprecated. Use the
>   verifyText command with an element locator instead.

You should use VerifyText going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i can see that command in IDE. can u verify again?[image: VerifyTextcommand]

It tells that the command is deprecated and that you will have to use verifyText command.

Comment: Hi @Mrunal, I'm also able to see it in command, but unable to see it when i right click in mozilla browser.

Comment: that method is deprecated so you will have to use verifyText method